# Resizing on detecting browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

Hey everyone very new to the whole JS and JQuery scene and need a little help. Ran through a few searches but I couldn't find the solution or overlooked it (or even implemented it wrong) .

I created a site using CreateJS and managed to get the resizing working pretty well (using a little JQuery i found on here). However, the code ONLY works on resizing, not when I load the browser window in a minimized state (basically loads the entire canvas as if it were fullscreen, cutting off the site).

I am trying to make this site automatically viewable on any resolution and mobile devices. Here is the code I am working with, some direction would be great!

```
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;



function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
images = images||{};

var manifest = [
    {src:"images/Bitmap1.png", id:"Bitmap1"},
    {src:"images/Bitmap2.png", id:"Bitmap2"},
    {src:"images/Bitmap3.png", id:"Bitmap3"},
    {src:"images/Bitmap4.png", id:"Bitmap4"},
    {src:"images/facebook.png", id:"facebook"},
    {src:"images/mainbg.jpg", id:"mainbg"},
    {src:"images/mainbglarge.jpg", id:"mainbglarge"}
];

var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
loader.loadManifest(manifest);
}


//resize jquery
(function($){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    windowResize();                      
  });         
})(jQuery);

function windowResize(){
   stage.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;    
   var test = (window.innerWidth/1680)*1; 
   exportRoot.scaleX = exportRoot.scaleY = test;
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete() {
    exportRoot = new lib.strikersite_html5Resize();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();
    stage.enableMouseOver();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(12);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
```

I'm basically using regular Javascript with elements of Jquery , so both approaches would be appreciated with this code in mind! Thanks!

Comment: You can manually trigger a resize after binding the handler: `$(window).resize(handlerFn).trigger('resize')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem right, just try to trigger the resize event on load. Just put it at the end of your 'script' block.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU!, this fixed the problem perfectly. I knew i had to use s window load somehow, but I was clearly using it in the wrong part of the code1

Comment: @Encee_209 Where is window load in this answer?

Comment: Oops, I think I was referring to your answer below in my excitement as I tried both approaches out of curiosity. Sorry about the mix up, and once again thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 0):

To manually trigger the resize event seems like a hack, I would call the function on the load or ready event.

Call `windowResize()` on window load or document ready:

```
$(window).load(windowResize());
```

The difference between window load and document ready is that window load fires when everything has been loaded, assets and document. document ready fires as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated. That said, use window load if you need to wait for images to calculate the dimensions on the canvas, otherwise just document ready will be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I could only "accept" one answer but this works just as well, I putting it in the wrong area initially ><